# How do I prevent SuperAgent AJAX from calling OPTIONS?

Tags: ajax, superagent

I found the source of my problem for SuperAgent (http://visionmedia.github.com/superagent/) on Firefox. Not sure if SuperAgent is doing it in its AJAX call or if FireFox is triggering it.

Essentially, every time I make an AJAX call an OPTIONS method is being fired on the URL before the actual AJAX call. Quite annoying since the server currently doesn't support OPTIONS. How can I make a call without it going to crap and re-coding the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok found out some more details. Thankfully testing on Safari gave me more insight into what was actually happening and I applied my knowledge here.

It seems to be the standard that browsers are calling an `OPTIONS` method before making an actual AJAX call. Seems a bit overbearing.

So to get around it I simply added a catch-all in my reverse proxy server to handle each `OPTIONS` call. You can see the question below for the code:

[Play! 2.0 easy fix to OPTIONS response for router catch-all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256241/play-2-0-easy-fix-to-options-response-for-router-catch-all)

And if you want to read up more on why browsers are doing this, see here:

[Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/jquery-why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-insted-of-a-get-request)

`OPTIONS` is from the CORS standard.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling web-secuty in phantomjs also helped to resolve this problem ([--web-security=no](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference)). Because I didn't have access to API server to make changes for OPTION method.