# Play! 2.0 easy fix to OPTIONS response for router catch-all?

Tags: ajax, playframework-2.0, http-options-method

Having some annoying issues making AJAX calls simply because almost every browser these days is making an OPTIONS call to the server before the actual AJAX call.

Since I am using Play! 2.0, is there any easy way to make a wildcard response to any route using the OPTIONS method?

For instance, in my routes do something like:
`OPTIONS /*  controllers.Options.responseDef`

*Yes* I am aware that the new Play! doesn't have a wildcard built-in, but there needs to be a solution for this since all browsers are increasingly calling OPTIONS before AJAX calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite a wildcard, but you can use a `route` which spans several slash-segments:

```
OPTIONS   /*wholepath     controllers.Options.responseDef(wholepath)
OPTIONS   /               controllers.Options.responseDef
```

It should match all the requests:

```
OPTIONS    /a
OPTIONS    /a/b
OPTIONS    /a/b/c
```

Note: that's from the top of my head, so maybe you'll need to polish it. I can't check it now by myself.

Check the section [Dynamic parts spanning several /](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaRouting) of the manual.

Comment: Interesting, is *wholepath a recently added feature? I just upgraded to 2.0.1 this seems like a "fresh" feature ;) I'll test it out and let you know if it works :)

Comment: Nope, it's available since 2.0 (0) I think, don't remember, what's more important I just realised, we can use it to solve other routing problems, ie. for avoiding redundant trailing  slashes: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/yGCubIgnP2o/lFOUl0Ccvw8J :) BTW of course `wholepath` is just a name of variable, you can use any other name, the most important is asterisk before the name `*some` instead of colon `:some`

Comment: Seems to be something wrong here...that route (and regex routes) won't compile with `Cannot use a method returning play.api.mvc.SimpleResult`

Comment: weird, I was testing this and it worked, but it was tested with Java actions. is your `responseDef` valid Play's action ?

Comment: Correct I just added a `def` to another controller and referenced it as usual. I am going to try an upgrade to `2.0.2` and see if it fixes it.

Comment: I was testing it with `2.0.1` and `2.0.2`, in this topic there should not be any differences between the versions.

Comment: Ah this is my mistake, a typo. I screwed up the `= Action {` bit. All good :)

Answer (score 1):

A very clean way to have a single controller endpoint match all OPTIONS requests is to override the `onRouteRequest` method of [Play's Global object](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal). The following version of `onRouteRequest` will route all requests to a single endpoint named `OptionsController.options`.

```
import play.api.mvc._

...

override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
  request.method match {
    case "OPTIONS" => Some(OptionsController.options)
    case _ => super.onRouteRequest(request)
  }
}
```