# Angularjs - $resource causing a 404 - method: OPTIONS

Tags: angularjs, controller, http-status-code-404

I am trying to get a basic $resource request via angularjs. I am running this on my local computer.

However, I get a 404. A simple get request on the browser loads the json. 
Here is the request shown by chrome devtools. (Question: why is the request mode: OPTIONS? Could that be the problem?)

```
Request URL:http://example.com/api/rentable_properties.json
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

Here is my controller that is attempting to make the request:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('adminApp')
.factory('Property', function($resource)
{
  return $resource('http://example.com/api/rentable_properties.json/:propertyId');
});

angular.module('adminApp')
  .controller('PropertiesCtrl', function ($scope, Property, $location) {
    $scope.properties = Property.query()
```

Comment: Stack Overflow thought my original answer was too short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @JSager, the problem was a cross domain issue.

Since I had control over the server side (running a Rails server), I had to change the server to it to receive cross-site requests.

In my case, I had to install a gem and follow it's instructions.

https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors

This fixed the issue for me. No changes made on the Angularjs based app.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you had responded until today.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is that your browser is running into a cross domain issue

See http://metajack.im/2010/01/19/crossdomain-ajax-for-xmpp-http-binding-made-easy/ for an explanation and [Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/jquery-why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-insted-of-a-get-request) for a question basically the same as yours.

Comment: okay ... although is there a fix specifically for angularjs apps?