# Headers don't set in javascript

Tags: javascript, http-headers

When I send XHR with custom headers and GET method I have problems:

1. Method changes to OPTION
2. Headers are not set

My request:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("GET", "http://api.pms.dev/v1/users", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic " + 'dsfsdfsdfsdfdsf');

    xhr.send();
```

Response body:

```
Remote Address:192.168.56.121:80
Request URL:http://api.pms.dev/v1/users
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:401 Unauthorized

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,de;q=0.2,it;q=0.2,uk;q=0.2,es;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.pms.dev
Origin:null
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/34.0.1847.116 Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Is it a CORS request ?

Comment: How is Angular involved?

Comment: Sorry, my first try was with using angularjs, then I understood that problem is not in angular

Comment: Here I found an answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13030629/2925732