# How to send HTTP headers in ReactJS using fetch()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const URL = "http://url.com";
fetch(URL).then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
    this.setState({ someData: json });
});
```

How to send HTTP request with HTTP headers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch GET Request with custom headers ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862202/fetch-get-request-with-custom-headers-reactjs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
fetch('your_url', { 
   method: 'get', 
   headers: new Headers({
     // Your header content
   })
 });
```

Comment: Why use `new Headers` here? Why don't you just use `headers: { ... }`?

Comment: Check https://github.github.io/fetch/#Headers, The option can take either object or Headers. Maybe fetch api internally converts object to Headers. Thus i have passed direct Headers to fetch option.

Comment: @konekoya Array or Headers object both are acceptable

Answer (score 4):

You can just pass them into `fetch()`:

```
const API = 'foo';

fetch(API, { headers: {
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
  'content-type': 'application/json'
}}).then()
```

You can read more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `fetch()` method you should do something like this

```
fetch(url, {
    ...    
    headers: {
       'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
       'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
```

For more details, look at the [Mozilla Developers documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Headers).