# Quickest and simplest way to convert fetch JavaScript to work in TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, fetch-api

What's the simplest way to get this piece of code working in TypeScript project?

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow',
  headers: {
    'x-mock-response-code': '204',
  },
}

fetch(
  'https://abcd.mock.pstmn.io/token',
  requestOptions
)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
```

I get this error that won't let me compile:

[image]

```
Argument of type '{ method: string; body: string; redirect: string; headers: { 'x-mock-response-code': string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestInit'.
   Types of property 'redirect' are incompatible.
     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'RequestRedirect | undefined'.ts(234
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch GET Request with custom header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862202/fetch-get-request-with-custom-header)

Comment: You need a more specific type for the value of (at least) `redirect`. Try `as const`, or inlining the options, or an explicit type for `requestOptions`, or ...

Comment: my issue is typescript related, it's typescript error...

Comment: Basically the same question, but in Angular: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62651724/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you assigned a plain object to `requestOptions` without specifying a type, TypeScript has inferred what type it should be.

That type thinks `redirect` is a string, but `fetch` expects it to be one of a specific selection of strings.

When you later pass the object to `fetch`, TypeScript thinks the value you used can be *any* string and you get an error.

You have a couple of options here:

- **Be explicit about the types**

  That way when you pass the object to `fetch` it will be of the `RequestInit` type instead of the inferred type you are currently passing.

  ```
    var requestOptions: RequestInit = {
  ```
- **Don't use the intermediate variable**

  If you assign the object directly to the argument, then TypeScript can compare it directly instead of creating a type and then comparing that type.

  ```
    fetch(
        'https://abcd.mock.pstmn.io/token',
        {
            // options here
        }
    )
  ```

Comment: You can also [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) either the whole `requestOptions` object or just the string `'follow'`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62652353/3001761

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to specify the type of your `requestOptions` object:

```js
var requestOptions: RequestInit = {
  method: 'GET',
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow',
  headers: {
    'x-mock-response-code': '204',
  },
}
```