# AJAX jQuery form submit sending twice POST & OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm having difficulty working out why my *AJAX* code is being sent twice on form submit.

*OPTIONS* request and a *POST* request - both 200 status messages. The POST request is successful and returns what I want so that is all good. I do not want the OPTIONS request to occur.

Thought it might have something to do with *CORS* or unbinding the submit event handler?

If anyone can help that would be great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="loginform">
        Username: <input type="text" class="rname" name="username" value=""/>
        Password:  <input type="text" class="rpass" name="password" value=""/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

scripts = function () {
    var _t = this;
    var authenticateUrl = "http://...";
    this.events = function () {
        $('#loginform').submit(_t.loginEvent);
    };
    this.loginEvent = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this);

            var _name = $form.find(".rname").val();
            var _pass = $form.find(".rpass").val();

            var submitData= {username: _name,password: _pass};
            submitData = JSON.stringify(submitData);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: authenticateUrl,       
                data: submitData,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("Success loginEvent");
                    if (data.error) {
                        console.log("Unsuccessful Login");
                    } else {
                        console.log("successful Login");
                    }
                }
            });
        };

    this.init = function () {
        _t.events();
    };
    this.init();
    return (this);
};

var LZ = new scripts();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its nothing weird about it if you are getting the response correctly.

`Options` request is used to allows the client to determine the options and/or requirements associated with a resource, or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action or initiating a resource retrieval.

`OPTIONS` requests are what we call `pre-flight` requests in Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS).

They are necessary when you're making requests across different origins.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for your answer. Makes sense, I got a bit confused as I used POSTMAN and a normal form with method and action and only got the POST status message, so it has to do with the AJAX request itself?

Comment: Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same origin policy. Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions.so you want need pre-flight request in case of POSTMAN as it is extension

Comment: It has to do with server.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. So assuming I have my files on the same domain (my http:// url) the options cross domain shouldn't show?