# Pre signed url PUT does a GET request in the background?

Tags: amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

uploading a image/jpeg to s3 bucket with PUT works fine, but just before the put the javascript throws an error saying it tried to do a GET using that signed key anT request in the first place. When i check the network in the browser it shows an OPTIONS method call with 200 status OK and then a PUT call using the signed url with 200 OK and no GET calls. Still the console throws the GET error.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer in the following post: [Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request)

Before every PUT request there is an OPTIONS ajax request which does a GET for that key. Apparently these PUT cross origin request are preflighted with OPTIONS call