# OPTIONS request is not firing with http call through Angular2 Http

Tags: angularjs, cors, angular

I am playing a bit with Angular2 structure and I got to the point where I want to pull information from the server.
Now, my api's domain is different from the FrontEnd app, and I am expecting that the browser will fire `OPTIONS` request before executing the actual one. However, that is not happening. Instead, what I get is an error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/rrm/api/v1/goals.
>   (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

And my network log looks like this:
[image]

My dead simple Angular2 code is as follows:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  goals: Object[];

  constructor(public authHttp: AuthHttp) {}

  ngOnInit():any {
    this.getGoals();
  }

  getGoals() {
    this.authHttp.get('http://localhost:8080/rrm/api/v1/goals')
        .subscribe(
            data => this.goals = data.arrayBuffer(),
            err => console.log('Error ', err),
            () => console.log('Request Complete')
        );
  }
}
```

What am i missing? I am not getting `options` request on the server and I don't see it in the browser...

Thanks,

Comment: you have to enable `CORS` at server side.

Comment: What does it mean, I have to enable it on the server side? I am not even getting the request on the server side... And how is it even related to server side?

Comment: http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, there are two main cases in CORS:

- **Simple requests**. We are in this case if we use HTTP methods `GET`, `HEAD` and `POST`. In the case of `POST` method, only content types with following values are supported: `text/plain`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`. Even if you're in these case and if you use a custom header (a header that you define by your own in your request), you'll fall into the preflighted request.
- **Preflighted requests**. When you aren't in the case of simple requests, a first request (with HTTP method `OPTIONS`) is done to check what can be done in the context of cross-domain requests.

In your case, you're in the first case (simple request).

Moreover your GET request should define a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in its response not to have the error. This will allow the browser to determine if you're (localhost:3000 for example) able to execute the request.

This article could interest you:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/

Answer (score -1):

The `OPTIONS` is only sent befor every `POST` request. For `GET` requests an `OPTIONS` preflight request is only sent if you have custom headers like auth-headers.

See also [Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request)