# JSON-RPC is not working with $http.POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, xmlhttprequest

I am developing an ionic hybrid mobile app and  trying to post data in JSON-RPC service but I am getting "**500 internal server error**"

```
        var req = {

        url: 'http://192.118.1.214:8080/remote/json-rpc',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0'
        },

        data: { jsonrpc: "2.0", id: 2, method: "HDAccess/getDevices", params: [null] }
    }


    $http(req).then(function (res) { alert(res); return res; },
                    function (er) { alert(er); });
```

It is the request details from webconsole. I have used chrome CORS plugin to avoid "CORS" issue

```
Request URL:http://192.118.1.214:8080/remote/json-rpc
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:192.118.1.214:8080
Response Headers
view source
cache-control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
content-length:810
content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
date:Tue, 01 Mar 2016 08:00:50 GMT
pragma:no-cache
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, cache-control, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:192.118.1.214:8080
Origin:http://evil.com/
Referer:http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
```

I have used the same url and post method in POSTMAN extension and got worked but it is not worked in the above code.

Find the POSTMAN inputs below

[image]

I have three doubts:

1.Why the data is not mentioned in the above request details.

2.Why the method is showed as "Option" but i am using "POST" method

3.why is it not working by code but working fine in the chrome POSTMAN extention client

Please guide me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the data is not mentioned in the above request details.

The data would be in the POST/PUT request that the browser would send if the server responded to the OPTIONS request with permission.

> Why the method is showed as "Option" but i am using "POST" method

Since you are sending a request with a JSON formatted body, you are triggering a preflight OPTIONS request.

See also [Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request)

> I have used chrome CORS plugin to avoid "CORS" issue

… it doesn't appear to be able to handle OPTIONS requests, at least not when the server responds with a `500 Internal Server Error`.

Fix your server so it can respond to OPTIONS requests.

> why is it not working by code but working fine in the chrome POSTMAN extention client

Because when you use Postman, there isn't a third party involved, so there are no trust issues to worry about. See also [XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.[website].com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com/35553666#35553666)

Comment: Really a great explanation and i can understand the problem now.
 Could you please tell me that what kind of changes needs to be done from the server side?

Comment: You need to respond to the OPTIONS with with a 200 OK and appropriate CORS headers.

Comment: I added the "OPTION" method,but iam getting the following error.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.118.1.254:8000/system/http/login. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://evil.com/, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:8101' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: The error message seems clear enough. Send the correct value for the header in the response.

Comment: Can we sent 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' value from front-end in the Header?

Comment: @rightPath — No. It would be stupid if the browser let your JavaScript give itself permission to read data (as if it was the user of the browser) from third party sites.

Comment: Yeah,I can understand,but in the server side i has given  value for  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  as *,evil.com,localhost:8101 (I have added these only for some testing purpose only) but i am getting error as "No access-control-allow-orgin" is present in the request header. Orgin localhost:8101is therefore not allowed,status code 500"

Comment: @rightPath — Then you (a) Need to set the correct value, remember the error message you had before "contains multiple values 'evil.com, *', but only one is allowed" and (b) Need to figure out why that makes the server side code you haven't put in the question is generating a 500 error in the first place.