# php file_get_contents("php://input") adding quotes

Tags: php, angularjs, json, file-get-contents, ngresource

I'm having issues using POST with a php REST server.
`file_get_contents("php://input")` is adding additional quotes.
This is causing `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true)` to
fail

i.e.
I am posting stringified JSON

```js
'{"someValue":0,"someOtherValue":1}'
```

PHP:

```
var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"))
```

returns

```
string(173) "'{  "someValue" : 0,   "someOtherValue" : "1"}'"
```

My PHP version is 5.3.10

To post the json, I am currently using the webstorm REST Client tool

```
Headers: 
    Accept: */*
Request Body:
    Text: '{  "someValue" : 0,   "someOtherValue" : "1"}'
```

I tried removing the outer quotes from the string in webstorm and it would work I.E. `{  "someValue" : 0,   "someOtherValue" : "1"}`

I moved to debugging in webstorm after initially hitting the bug in an angular application using angular ngResource

Controller

```
angular
    .module('app.bookings')
    .controller('BookAPuntController', BookAPuntController);
BookAPuntController.$inject(BookingServices);
function BookAPuntController(BookingServices) {
    var data = {
      someValue:0,
      someOtherValue:1
    };
    BookingServices.save(JSON.stringify(data));
};
```

booking.dataservice.js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.data')
    .factory('BookingServices', BookingServices);

  BookingServices.$inject = ['$resource'];

  /* @ngInject */
  function BookingServices($resource) {
    return $resource('rest/booking/:Id/:from/:to', null, {
      'get': {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
    });
  }

})();
```

Comment: Show the code that POSTS's the json String

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be outputting with the single ticks `'`.  If you can't modify what it's output, then `preg_replace("@(^'|'$)@", '', file_get_contents("php://input"))`

Comment: How are you feeding in the JSON?

Comment: I've updated the question with my input. @DataHerder the single ticks are being created by JSON.stringify

Comment: @rgunning - then I think the post below that answers your question is probably correct.  When you JSON.stringify, you want to pass the actual object, not a string representation of that object.  `JSON.stringify({'something': 'else'})` rather than `JSON.stringify('{"something":"else"}')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'{"someValue":0,"someOtherValue":1}'; // IS A STRING...
 {"someValue":0,"someOtherValue":1};  // IS NOT A STRING...
```

If you are passing-in the first variant; You should get back a String like PHP smartly figured out and returned...

```
string(173) "'{  "someValue" : 0,   "someOtherValue" : "1"}'"
```

When you pass in the result of

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
```

You may have solved your Problem, Yourself....

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was asking the entirely wrong question

My angular application was failing with it's POST due to CORS. I was running the App on localhost but querying the remote REST php server. When I ran the application a method OPTIONS request was being sent due to CORS. The server didn't know how to respond so everything failed.

debugging in webstorm was artificially introducing the error seen in the original question.

[Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request)

https://serverfault.com/questions/231766/returning-200-ok-in-apache-on-http-options-requests