# Vue.js click event firing twice with vue-resource

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-resource

when i click at button to fire my function, my request is called twice, is calling a api endpoint, at first request, my authorization token is not included, and at second request it is, and i get a error 401 unauthorized on console.

error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.myurl.dev/educational/filials. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

when i use `var_dump(getallheaders()); die;` on my api, i can see the two requests

[image]

and that is my code in **main.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import router from './router/routes.js'
import App from './App.vue'

const TOKEN = 'eyJ0eXAiO...'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(Vuex)

/* eslint-disable no-new */

// Start
new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})

Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  // modify headers
  request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + TOKEN)
  request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
  next()
})
```

and my **App.vue**:

```
<template>
     <div id="app">
        <img src="./assets/logo.png" alt="">
        <button type="button" @click="getFilial">Get Filial</button>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      data () {},
      getFilial () {
        this.$http.get('http://api.myurl.dev/educational/filials').then(response => {
          console.log(response.data)
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

this is what i get with var_dump at first request:

```
array (size=10)
  'Host' => string 'api.uniesp.dev' (length=14)
  'Connection' => string 'keep-alive' (length=10)
  'Access-Control-Request-Method' => string 'GET' (length=3)
  'Origin' => string 'http://localhost:8080' (length=21)
  'User-Agent' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36' (length=108)
  'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => string 'authorization' (length=13)
  'Accept' => string '*/*' (length=3)
  'Referer' => string 'http://localhost:8080/' (length=22)
  'Accept-Encoding' => string 'gzip, deflate, sdch' (length=19)
  'Accept-Language' => string 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' (length=35)
```

and that is what i get at second request (correct):

```
array (size=9)
  'Host' => string 'api.uniesp.dev' (length=14)
  'Connection' => string 'keep-alive' (length=10)
  'Accept' => string 'application/json' (length=16)
  'Origin' => string 'http://localhost:8080' (length=21)
  'User-Agent' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36' (length=108)
  'Authorization' => string 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOi' (length=577)
  'Referer' => string 'http://localhost:8080/' (length=22)
  'Accept-Encoding' => string 'gzip, deflate, sdch' (length=19)
  'Accept-Language' => string 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' (length=35)
```

Comment: Is the first one [OPTIONS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request) call?

Comment: yes, is coming as request method OPTIONS. why?

Comment: but the problem is, i'm still have this problem with the event 'click' being fired twice, the first request sends this OPTIONS and the second not..