# Why is my my rest url called twice?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe, dojo

My javascript code looks like below :

```
function copysave(){
    dojo.io.iframe.send({
    form:dojo.byId("formId"),
    method: "POST",
    //handleAs: "html",
    encoding : "utf-8",
    url :"/CopyReplace/copysavefirst",
    load: function(response) {
        txtResponse = response;
        alert("respone: "+txtResponse);
        console.log(" success : txtResponse"+txtResponse)
    },
    error: function(error, ioArgs) {
        console.log("bulkcopy() ERROR :: " + error);
        console.log("bulkcopy() ioArgs :: " + ioArgs);
        return error;
    }
  });
}
```

My Html looks like below :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formId" method="">
<button name="save" id="submitValues" value="Finish" onclick="copysave()" >Finish</button>
```

If I click on finish, I can see `/CopyReplace/copysavefirst` hitting the server two times. 
Could some one please tell me what to do to call only once? 
Also, it is going to the error section.

Comment: Look for type one would be OPTIONS and one would be POST in cross domain prior to any call an option call is an pre-flight request

Comment: Probably the first call is just a HEAD request and then it gets a 100-continue, to which it replies again, this time with the POST data.

Comment: @Nehal I am actually triggering a job for this. So, it's getting called twice and the job is triggered twice.

Comment: @VinodLouis I didn't get you. I should use OPTIONS?

Comment: @POOJAHEGDE no 2 calls will be made when you do a cross doamin request the option call is a pre-flight request to check the cors access later  follwer by the real POST/PUT/GET/DELETE call inspect the network console you will see OPTIONS and POST call

Comment: try using enctype="text/plain".

Comment: @POOJAHEGDE Look in browser console if you see two calls you can see there one would be for `OPTIONS` and other would be `POST`

Comment: @POOJAHEGDE for better understanding go through it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request

Comment: @VinodLouis I checked both the calls. Both are returning the same response data from server. Even though I am receiving 200 response code for both the calls, I am getting error logs in error callback().
Instead of allowing a pre-flight, can't we just call the real POST req?

Comment: @ POOJAHEGDE which language are you using on the file which is calling by ajax?