# Why does my serverless Lambda function reject Cache-Control header?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-headers, aws-lambda, fine-uploader, serverless-framework

I'm using FineUploader to upload files to S3. While utilizing the DELETE functionality I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/deleteS3File?.
>   Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

The lambda function was created using the awesome Serverless Framework with the following configuration:

```
functions:
  deleteS3File:
    handler: handler.deleteS3File
    events:
      - http:
          path: deleteS3File
          method: POST
          integration: lambda
          cors: true
          response:
            headers:
              Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```

Any idea what this error means for a Lambda function and how to tackle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [POST verb preflights an OPTIONS verb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13030629/1476885) that you don't support.

So, you need to create a method for OPTIONS that will return status code 200 (success) and with the expected headers.

For both the OPTIONS and POST, try the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, DELETE"
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Cache-Control, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers"
```

<sup>you may fine tune the headers later to allow just what you need</sup>

Comment: just to refine the answer - I created a serverless OPTIONS function that merely returns the specified access-control-allow-headers.