# $http.put request changing into OPTIONS request in AngularJS 1.3.15

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yii2, angular-http

I'm new to the AngularJS. I'm using AngularJS 1.3.15 version. When I try to call an api with PUT method, It's generating OPTIONS request. I don't know where I'm doing mistake. I tried so many methods which is suggested in Stockoverflow, but still I'm not getting anything. Please help me to resolve this issue. below are my Controller, Models, html files and Chrome developer tool network activity screenshot.

Controller file users.js

```
'use strict';
mmlApp_users.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/users/update/:userId', {
      templateUrl: 'views/users/update.html',
      controller: 'update',
      resolve: {
        user: function(users, $route){
          var userId = $route.current.params.userId
          return users.getUser(userId);
        }
      }
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/users/index'
    });
}]);
```

Model file - users.js

```
'use strict';
mmlApp_users.factory('users', ['$http', '$location', '$route', function($http, $location, $route){
  var obj = {}; 

  obj.getUser = function(userId){
    return $http.get(serviceBase + 'users/view/'+userId);
  };

  obj.updateUser = function(user){
    var config = {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        };
    var userParams = {
        first_name: user.first_name, 
        last_name: user.last_name, 
        email: user.email, 
        password: user.password,
        address: user.address,
        state: user.state,
        city: user.city,
        zip_code: user.zip_code
      };
    $http.put(serviceBase + 'users/update/'+user.id+'?access-token=8e0bb9b3-b35f-4d30-943d-6028c0b85c13', userParams, config)
          .then(successHandler).catch(errorHandler);

    function successHandler(){
      $location.path('/users/index');
    }
    function errorHandler(){
      alert('Oops! Somthing went wrong.');
      //$location.path('/users/create');
    }
  };

  return obj;
}]);
```

Views - update.html

```
<div>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <p>{{ message}}</p>
  <form role="form" name="myForm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class= "form-group col-md-6" ng-class="{error: myForm.first_name.$invalid}">
        <label> First Name: </label>
        <div>
          <input name="first_name" ng-model="user.first_name" type= "text" class= "form-control" placeholder="First Name" required/>
          <span ng-show="myForm.first_name.$dirty && myForm.first_name.$invalid" class="help-inline">First Name Required</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class= "form-group col-md-6" ng-class="{error: myForm.last_name.$invalid}">
        <label> Last Name: </label>
        <div>
          <input name="last_name" ng-model="user.last_name" type= "text" class= "form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
          <span ng-show="myForm.last_name.$dirty && myForm.last_name.$invalid" class="help-inline">Last Name Required</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    ....
    ....
    ....

    <a href="#/users/index" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
    <button ng-click="updateUser(user);" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

In chrome developer tool network activity screenshot - 
[image]

Comment: That's just part of sending a CORS request. Fix the server so it handles it properly.

Comment: May I know why this question is down voted? If anything is wrong please tell me I try to correct it next time.

Comment: lack of research. Nothing in your question seems to indicate that you even know what CORS is.

Comment: Although this is POST and not GET, look at this question: [Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request).

Comment: @KevinB for api side i'm using PHP. I already added this header in my api entry file - header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Comment: that's not enough to handle preflights. Your server is responding with 405, but it needs to instead respond with 200.

Comment: @KevinB please tell me how to handle preflights. I'm not aware of it.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for sharing that link. I will check now.

Comment: it depends on the server unfortunately.

Comment: @KevinB This issue happen only in case of PUT request. But GET and POST is working fine for me. So I hope server or API side not an issue.

Comment: Right, CORS has rather strict rules on what requires a preflight and what doesn't. GET and POST requests that don't change the contentType header or otherwise add additional headers don't require a preflight.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150346/discussion-between-manikandan-s-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score -1):

try in your factory:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
mmlApp_users.factory('users', ['$http', '$location', '$route','$httpParamSerializer',
function ($http, $location, $route, $httpParamSerializer) {

    var obj = {};

    obj.getUser = function (userId) {
        return $http.get(serviceBase + 'users/view/' + userId);
    };

    obj.updateUser = function (user) {

        var userParams = {
            first_name: user.first_name,
            last_name: user.last_name,
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password,
            address: user.address,
            state: user.state,
            city: user.city,
            zip_code: user.zip_code
        };

        var req = {
            method: 'PUT',
            url: serviceBase + 'users/update/' + user.id + '?access-token=8e0bb9b3-b35f-4d30-943d-6028c0b85c13',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            },
            data: $httpParamSerializer(userParams)
        };

        $http(req)
            .then(successHandler)
            .catch(errorHandler);

        function successHandler() {
            $location.path('/users/index');
        }

        function errorHandler() {
            alert('Oops! Somthing went wrong.');
            //$location.path('/users/create');
        }
    };

    return obj;

}]);

})();
```

And Goog Lock :)