# Angular HTTP Client - 2 calls for every PUT/POST not GET

Tags: angular, rxjs

Every time I make a put or a post I see 2 calls:

1. Request Method:OPTIONS | Status Code:200
2. Request Method:POST | Status Code:201

For a GET I only see one call:

1. Request Method:GET | Status Code:200

My implementation of the PUT or POST

```
constructor(
 private http: HttpClient   
) {}    

postShortForm(shortForm: any) {
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.preCheckUrl, shortForm, {
  reportProgress: true,
});
return this.http.request(req)
  .retry(3)
}
```

GET

```
constructor(
 private http: HttpClient    
) {}    

getApplication(id: any){
interface ItemsResponse {
  results: string[];
}
return this.http
  .get<ItemsResponse>(this.applicationSubmitUrl+this.id.id, {observe: 'response'})
}
```

Is angular doing something under the hood to make an options request or is something in my code triggering it?

Comment: Please see this post : [OPTIONS requests](https://www.google.fr/search?q=options+request&oq=OPTIONS&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j69i61l2j69i60j0.1303j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request) (TL;DR: They're CORS preflight requests sent by the browser.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its because of CORS, like request was made at Site A (localhost:4200 or 192.168.1.1:9002) to Site B (192.168.1.1:9000)

The first request is the pre-flight check, to see if the client is allowed to make a request (like for example in the php code in the server its got something like this, denoting that CORS types of requests are allowed)

```php
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  ....
?>
```

the first request is type OPTIONS, the second request is the actual request, type GET or POST.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As per the `HttpClient` document the `post` method used code observable and will make 2 calls. Below is the note from `HttpClient` documentation

> Note the subscribe() method. All Observables returned from HttpClient
>   are cold, which is to say that they are blueprints for making
>   requests. Nothing will happen until you call subscribe(), and every
>   such call will make a separate request. For example, this code sends a
>   POST request with the same data twice:

see the details [angular HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: I'm not seeing 2 POSTs though. One is an options request.

Comment: Thats because in the documentation... there is 2 calls to subsbscribe....

Comment: what we are after is that, we need to know why on a single call to ".subscribe(...)" it is making 2 xhr calls.