# Angular HTTP Error Empty Untyped Response

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, promise, jhipster

I have an Angular/JHipster application that makes HTTP calls. I want to do error handling in my `Observable` subscriptions.

However, when the first time the error handler is invoked, the `err` object is not a response, it's a raw `{}` `Object`. All subsequent error handler invocations have a valid `Response`.

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

#### MyComponent.ts:

```
handleClickPost() {
    this.myService.doPost(this.body)
    .subscribe(
        (res: Response) => {
            this.responseOk = true;
        },
        (err: Response) => {
            // This is a HACK!
            // For some reason, the first time this error handler is invoked (after page load),
            // the response body is empty here and serializes to "{}".
            if (JSON.stringify(err) === '{}') {
                // first request always reaches here... WHY?
                this.handleClickPost(); // NB: workaround
                // err.json(); // results in null "method not found" error
            } else {
                // second request always reaches here... WHY?
                // (I want all requests to go here with a valid 'Response' object)
                this.showRequestFailed = true;
                this.errorResponse = err.json();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

#### MyService.ts:

```
doPost(body): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.post(this.resourceUrl, body);
}
```

My shoddy workaround is to just call the method again after the first empty-body failure in order to get a typed `Response`.

NB: This behavior happens with both Angular 2 and Angular 4.

Comment: can you post your service method `this.myService.doPost()` I think you are using Observable and not Promise in your service  method.

Comment: I usually use `any` type with error handler. Also you have to check from server side what response are you getting first time in case of error.If it's an object then check whether that object has the error response.

Comment: @Niladri: Ah, you're correct; I am using Observable (pasted MyService.ts). LMK if that helps guide to an answer.

Comment: I got this similar issue for my server side code where i was not returning the err response properly in a json encoded format. So I got `{}` as an empty object. This looks like an issue from your server side api.I use JSON.NET serializer to serialize the string into a JSON response, so it worked.

Comment: instead of using `JSON.stringify(err)` in the error handler can you simply use `console.log(err)` to see what is the content? it's supposed to be already serialized into json so you should not have to use `JSON.stringify` again.

Comment: also did you use `JSON.stringify(this.body)` before posting it ?

Comment: @Niladri: The POSTed body is correct JSON. The return response has a `Content-type` of `application/json` and is valid JSON.

Comment: Nothing guarantees the kind of value that will be thrown. It is perfectly valid for any value to signal an error. If you look at the type of the `error` callback function as declared by subscribe, it takes a value (the error) that is of type `any`. By explicitly _typing_ the argument in the provided callback (by writing `(err: Response) =>` you misleading yourself as to the _type_ of the object. There is no reason to necessarily expect a `Response` object and your client side Http layer may be returning something else. In general, annotating the type of a callback param is a bad practice.

Comment: By implication of my other comment, try to avoid the awful practices promoted by the Angular style guide. They often lead to bugs. Instead, learn to use TypeScript idiomatically by using it outside of Angular or without the Angular style guide.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to check few things to make sure your setup is correct.

1. Check in server side whether you are sending the proper JSON encoded response for the first time request i.e the response is correctly serialized or not.
2. check if the payload for the POST request `this.body` is already converted to json string or not if you are posting json data to server . You should use 
   `JSON.stringify(this.body)` before sending the request if you are sending json data.
3. you should use map()/catch()  in you `post()` method to actually map the response and catch the actual error.

So your code should look like below

**MyService.ts:**

```
doPost(body:any): Observable<Response> {
   let payload = JSON.stringify(body); // Stringify payload if you are using JSON data
   let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON for json request
   let options      = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option
   return this.http.post(this.resourceUrl, payload,options)
                        .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); //...errors if any;
}
```

**MyComponent.ts:**

```
handleClickPost() {
    this.myService.doPost(this.body)
    .subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
            this.responseOk = true;
        },
        (err: any) => {
            // Log errors if any
            console.log(err);
           }
        }
    );
}
```

or you can create a separate error handler for the `catch()` method like below

```
private handleError(error: any) {
      let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message : error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
       console.log(errMsg); // log to console instead
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
```

and use it this way `.catch(this.handleError)` in your service class.

Comment: Sorry, this is basically what I'm already doing: subscribing to the posted `Observable`.  I have tried a separate error handling method like `handleError`, but the problem is that the response is not a typed `Response`.

Comment: @JJZabkar have to check in server side what are you returning as response?

Comment: The server response is valid, as-expected JSON for all requests. The issue only occurs on the first call.

Comment: So what are u returning in the first call ? can you check that with `console.log(typeof err);`

Comment: Within the error handler callback method, I can see `typeof` `object`.

Comment: What response are you returning from server in first call? in my case I was returning a `string` but it was not  serialized so i was getting an empty `object`

Comment: The response that I can see in Chrome Network panel is well-formed JSON.

Comment: @Niladri  can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257097/typeerror-cannot-read-property-tigerstart-of-undefined/46257551#46257551

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an issue of preflight Http OPTIONS request. Did you verify the response type.

If it is this issue you can avoid the preflight request by modifying the content-header as below.

```
   $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "text/plain"
```

Read more here: [Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request)

Comment: I can confirm that this is *not* a preflight request. On the server side, I can see my `GET` endpoint is invoked and returns the expected error response body.