# angular 2 get call thorwing error, after status 200

Tags: node.js, angular, rest

I am calling my get rest service like this,

```
  makeGetCall(url: string): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new Headers({'auth-code': 'auth-code',
                                  'from':'app'});
    return this.http.get(AdminConstants.BASE_URL + this.SEPARATOR + url,{
      headers: headers
    })
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    console.log('extract data');
    console.log(res);
    const body = res.json();
    return body || {};
  }

  private handleErrorObservable(error: Response | any) {
    console.log('error in service');
    console.log(error.message);
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
  }
```

and My rest service is:

```
console.log('inside get all user');
        ApiUser.find().then(users => {
            console.log('length : '+users.length)
            res.status(200).send(users);
        }, error => {
            res.send(500).send(error);
        })
```

I am using MEAN stack for my application.
Here is my problem, when I am calling my rest service from postman its working.Even in the chrome/mozilla console I can see my response as expected.[response header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ptRK.png)[image: responseboby]

But from my angular 2 application my handleErrorObservable method is called and that too with an error without proper message.

I just installed ssl certificates on my server, before ssl this was working inside my application.
Also to add post requests are working.

I don't know what I am missing.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: This might be the issue of http preflight OPTIONS call. Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46123053/2015408)

Comment: This isn't a preflight request as data is being returned, but you are missing `Acess-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response headers, so it looks like a general CORS issue.

Comment: @SurenderKherwa will search on these lines

Comment: @KirkLarkin : in this I should not get the response also, right ?

Comment: Everything is returned as normal. It's actually the browser that effectively creates the error when CORS is not satisfied. You would need your response headers to include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or whatever your domain is instead of `*`. Treat this as a CORS issue and do some research. Also check the console in Chrome - You'll likely see an error in there.

Comment: @KirkLarkin thank you. Will search on this

Comment: @KirkLarkin : you were right. as soon as I added the response in my rest service it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @kirkLarkin

I just added res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');  in my rest service and it worked.