# POST request does not work from Angular5 code but works from Postman

Tags: angular, cors, http-post, postman

Frontend: Angular5

Backend: Java (Running on a Wildfly 8.x server)

On making an HTTP `POST` request with `content-type: 'application/json'` from my Angular application to the server, I get the following error:

> Failed to load http://localhost:8080/myk/api/v1/events/addevent:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

This is the code for the request:

`const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    };
 this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/myk/api/v1/events/addevent", 
                                    jsonPayload, 
                                    httpOptions).subscribe();`

On inspecting, I found that instead of a `POST` request, an `OPTIONS` request was being made (as in accordance with [this MDN article on CORS and preflighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)).

However, when I tried the same request using Postman, it worked perfectly fine.

How does Postman not face an issue with the `OPTIONS` request when I'm not handling the `OPTIONS` request at the server?

Also, what can I do (while maintaining the same `content-type` and without having to modify the server side code) to solve this issue?

**Note 1:** Although [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request) addresses the same issue, the suggested solution requires changing the content-type.

**Note 2:** When I run another application (designed, not by me, in Angularjs) which attempts to make a POST request using an `ajax` call, it works fine. (I do not understand why this works and, besides, an answer related to angular5 would be appreciated. I included this note in case it helps in figuring out the problem with the Angular5 application)

**EDIT:** This might be bordering on fussy, but I'm specifically looking to try to solve the above by modifying client side code and not by using extensions or any modifications related to the browser. However, if none of that is possible, I'm open to changing server-side code.

Comment: if you don't pass the headers, you won't get the OPTIONS call

Comment: In that case how do i specify that the data being sent is JSON? Also, in Postman, I have included a header indicating content type as application/json (while choosing raw data as the body type) and it still works

Comment: you better accept the header  in your backend code anyway, it's just one line of code.
You can't get away with not taking care of COREs

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value="/addevent",method=RequestMethod.POST,produces=org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<?> addNewEvent( @RequestBody   EventDTO event,HttpServletRequest request)` 
This is my current server side code's method'd signature. How is Postman still able to successfully access it and get JSON data across to the server?

Comment: "However, if none of that is possible, I'm open to changing server-side code." — You need to modify the server side code. It would be stupid if your client side could disable a security feature designed to stop your client side code from accessing other sites.

Comment: Okay. How can i accept option requests on the client side? (Considering that you're saying that the answer given is insufficient)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is known as **CORS**. **C**ross **O**rigin **R**esource **S**haring. This is arises when the origin of the request and response is different. For example: If your project is on **https://139.43.33.122:1111/** and your server is hosted on **https://123.0.3.444:3000**, then the origin of your request and response are completely different and thus, browser will block the response. This is the browser thing. Postman doesn't care about their origin. To receive response, there are 2 ways (maybe more but i use these 2 only).

1. **Additional Headers:** If yoou have access/permission to server code, then add an additional header to the server responses: 
   **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteA.com, Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type**.
2. **Use Extensions:** There are multiple extensions that can bypass this restriction. IF you do not have access or permission to change the server response, then this is the way to go.I'm personally using this method only.

Comment: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" — It's a preflighted request. That is insufficient.

Comment: "Use Extensions" — This is a hack for use during dev, and utterly impractical during production.

Comment: Thanks. I had previously tried using the CORS extension for Chrome, but it didnt seem to make a difference. There is nothing to be done after installing and switching on the extension, right (from what I saw, its only functionality seemed toggling it on and off)?

Comment: @Quentin Agreed about the extensions. I should've mentioned that in my question

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for reminding, i almost forgot the access control part and yes, extension is a dev hack.

Comment: @RahulSaha this is the extension which i use:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi. Sometimes you may need to toggle it 2-3 times to work but remember, as Quentin mentioned: this is just a dev hack. It is ok only if your project and server will hosted on the same origin. If not, then dont use it. It wont solve your problem as every user will need to have this extension installed on their system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I have found a trick to avoid both CORS and 403 error thanks to this [article](https://support.getpostman.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003702149-My-request-works-in-the-Postman-Chrome-app-but-not-in-the-OSX-Windows-Linux-app).

1. Add Postman Interceptor on your Google Chrome : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo/support?hl=en
2. Activate Postman Interceptor in Postman

[image]

3. Launch your request and capture the cookie thanks to Postman interface

[image]

4. Open your Chrome development tool, go to the console and add manually the cookie found thanks to postman interceptor

   document.cookie="keyofcookie=valueofcookie"

[image]

Retry your request, it works !

Otherwise, just to avoid CORS, you can use the proxy described [here](http://crossorigin.me).

Comment: Thanks, but isn't this a browser fix that each user will have to do individually?

Comment: Unfortunately, you're right. It is a really dirty solution. However, you can customize the cookie, make it timeless [https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie] and push it at the beginning of each user session. It is the only solution that I found.

Comment: LOL, you need to tell all your users to install interceptor to their browser LOLOLOOLOLOLOLOL