# I am getting error : OPTIONS http://10.100.8.58:8080/user/view 401 () ,

Tags: java, angular, http, spring-security, cors

My server side code is..

```
public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter {
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;



    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");


    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type,access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,authorization,x-requested-with");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}
```

}

My Client Side code is ...

```
viewUsers(): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');       
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic dXNlcjpzdXJpeWFu');

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(myurl, options).map(getJson);
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue...
I am getting above and below error : Failed to load http://10.100.8.58:8080/user/view: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401. I don't know where i have done a mistake.

MY server side securityConfif CLass is..

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("suriyan").roles("USER").and().withUser("admin")
            .password("suriyans").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER").antMatchers("/**")
            .hasRole("ADMIN").and().csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable();
}
```

}

My post man code is..

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

 Request request = new Request.Builder()
 .url("http://10.100.8.58:8080/user/view")
 .get()
 .addHeader("authorization", "Basic dXNlcjpzdXJpeWFu")
 .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
 .addHeader("postman-token", "48b3ca10-fe72-4a1e-ce00-44c78afb636a")
 .build();

 Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: I have used spring security and created scecurityConfig class for two roles in the name of user and admin in server side. By using postman i can get the data using my user and password but it not achievable via coding in client side.

Comment: can you post the all settings you are using in Postman?

Comment: is it working in the postman?

Comment: OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://10.100.8.58:8080/user/view")
  .get()
  .addHeader("authorization", "Basic dXNlcjpzdXJpeWFu")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("postman-token", "42485331-9259-1b83-e186-a0c563e4f44d")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

Comment: @ShadabFaiz Faiz Its working fine in postman

Comment: then this is related to CORS issue..looks this 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361030/post-request-does-not-work-from-angular5-code-but-works-from-postman/49361816#49361816

Comment: @ShadabFaiz I conclude its CORS issue by referring stackoverflow.com/questions/49361030/… but if its solvable then it will be helpful for me . Anyway thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is preflighted by the browser because **Same Origin Policy**. I think [this is a good description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681292/same-origin-policy-and-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing) about **SOP** and **CORS**.

In order to allow http request from different origin you have to enable **CORS** but this is done on the **server** using the header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'
```

You have declared this header on the client, which I think is wrong.
Here you have some examples about enabling **CORS** with Spring:

[Spring CORS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091524/spring-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: Yeah What you have said is Correct.. Now its working fine .. I have added a line
 @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }   in my securityConfig Class at bottom and i have removed the line "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*' " and Content Type header from client side now its working fine. Thank you for your Helpful answer.