# Angular cross origin issue in API call Backend PHP?

Tags: php, angular, codeigniter

Facing CORS in angular, when i was trying to make a API call between my localhost to another domain.I am getting 404 issue .

1.Front End : Angualr 7

## Front end request part:

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'POST',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
    })
  }
login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>('http://remote/djaxtesting/enter_uiupgrade/index.php/api/v1/user/validate',
        {acc_type: "ADMIN", uemail: "djax_admin@dreamajax.com", upw: "123456"},httpOptions)
            .pipe(map(user => {}))


    }
```

## Back end coding :

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

    public function validate_post()
    {

        $role = array('ADVERTISER','TRAFFICKER','ADMIN','MANAGER');

        if($this->post('acc_type') !='' and in_array($this->post('acc_type'),$role))
        {

            switch(strtoupper($this->post('acc_type')))
            {
                case "ADMIN":

                    $adminObj   =   $this->do_networks->validate_user($this->post('uemail'),$this->post('upw'),$this->post('acc_type'));
                    //$this->response($adminObj, 200);
    }
    }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Koqjc.png)

We using php for api. Helping handing needs to solve this issue ?

Comment: the status is  `404` meaning the url you are passing with the request doesn't exists. Check the url

Comment: Request url is correct.It works fine in postman tool.

Comment: Its working fine in postman tool

Comment: I think the problem with the options method see my answer.

Comment: could you be sending the header anywhere in your code? ie. `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");` and the actual problem being something different?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the option method. Option request should be a 200 returning an empty response. Then the browser will send the real POST request.

for that replace with the headers in your PHP File in the constructor. It will work.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
   $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
   if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
       die();
   }
```

Comment: Yes i am getting request method is "OPTIONS".But i request post call only in angular (Front End side)

Comment: Yes i tried your code set.
But i am not get inside the "Validate Function".Because my "Validate" function is post method
My PHP code: 


public function validate_post()
    {

$this->response('test',200);
    }
    }
    }

Comment: remove _post in your validate function and  echo anything. and let me know the response.

Comment: for why the option method is set. check this SO answer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request/13030629#13030629

Comment: I am using rest api in code igniter  for that we must use the "POST or GET"  methods .If i removed same error occured

Comment: this is very simple in CodeIgniter.add header code in the constructor.it will work.

Comment: function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
 
  
 }

Comment: I added like above in constructor and tried also .But getting same error still.

Comment: add this after the header in constructor $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
   if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
       die();
   }