# JS fetch header parameters on request are not assumed properly

Tags: javascript, header, fetch, bearer-token

I am trying to request an API using fetch in javascript.
I did it in the simplest way, just declaring the method I am using and the header with the api key and auth.:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer 0123456789",
        "x-api-key": "9876543210"
    }
})
```

The request sent by the browser changes the original fetch request:

- The method sent is "OPTIONS" instead of "GET".
- The header parameters (api key and auth) are included on "Access-Control-Request-Header" instead to be included directly on the header.

[see how it is sent by the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBXAN.png)

How can I avoid the browser to change the method and keep the api key and auth. directly on the request header?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is a preflight thing afaik; the browser is making sure that the server supports the request you want to send. The actual GET request should follow if the OPTIONS request goes through.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as written: this is a preflight request.
Issue has been explained.
Further infos on [Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request)